# Question about Chopin nocturne in c music sheet

Tags: piano

How to count those notes? I marked them

[image]

Comment: @Peter - doubtful. I guess OP has missed seeing the triplet mark, thus believing the dotted crotchet is too long to fit in the bar.

Comment: ... and in the first measure you have no problems with counting?

Answer (score 0):

Look very carefully at the preceding three quavers. They have a tiny '3' attatched to them. That means those three get played in the time of two similar quavers - for a count of '1&'. The B♯s come in on '2' and last for the count of 2&3, with the final note in the bar landing on the & of 3.

C♯ minor is more accurate than 'C'!

Comment: "C♯ minor is more accurate than 'C'!" Calling C# minor "C" would be like calling a strawberry an apple.